# How to add a border on a table to a generated file from PrinceXML?

Tags: html, css, pdf, princexml

I try to put a border on a table for printview and in pdf file. It works in the printview of the most of browsers but when I generated a pdf which use the same css file, it doesn't work.
To generate the pdf file I use PrinceXML.

Do you know how to add the borders in css for PrinceXML ?

Comment: I took the freedom to edit away wrongly-named *PrincePDF* and replace them by *PrinceXML* (as the tag says).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
table, tr, td { border: 1px solid black !important }
```